# How to change column names after importing a csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Some original column names have spaces, so I cannot use: `df.Column Name.unique()` to get the unique value in the column. It shouldn't have spaces.
Is there a way I can get rid of spaces, replace them with `_` (underscore), or is it just easier to replace them? But it needs to be after import of csv.

Comment: Can you post an example of your data, if you just want to replace spaces with underscores you can just do `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')` if you want to strip them are they leading, trailing, embedded?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to replace spaces with underscores using list comprehension:

```
df.columns = [x.replace(' ', '_') for x in df.columns]
```

I typically also use lower() method to make slicing up the data easier (I don't need to remember which words are upper case).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the column, you can do the same with:

```
df['Column Name'].unique()
```